# How can I display vcs revision of Python package installed with pip from vcs?

Tags: python, version-control, pip

After installing some package with pip from vcs like this
`pip install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git@355b97165c#requests`
how can I display the vcs revision/commit/branch/tag (355b97165c in this example) used to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this because url used during installation is not being recorded anywhere. However there's work in progress to add such functionality. See [Continuing Feature/record download info](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/507) pull request.

I'd like to thank dstufft from #pip IRC channel for answering my question and pointing me to this pull request (which builds upon his pull request).