# pip freeze reports version number instead of git sha for certain package

Tags: python, git, pip

Typically, when I pip install -e from a git repo, and then do "pip freeze", it gives me git version info. For example:

```
$ pip install -e git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git@27b55a74d7b9bd2f8c60fd0ee342bcbbf40e0a66#egg=requests-dev
$ pip freeze | grep requests
-e git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git@27b55a74d7b9bd2f8c60fd0ee342bcbbf40e0a66#egg=requests-dev
```

Why is it that when I do this with the piplint package, "pip freeze" reports the version number instead of the git details?

```
$ pip install -e git://github.com/dcramer/piplint.git@cb2752e0c9692e4df2b2b03dec3087699e90f4da#egg=piplint
$ pip freeze | grep piplint
piplint==0.1.1
```

Comment: related: [How can I display vcs revision of Python package installed with pip from vcs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10856778/95735)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When "pip freeze" tries get vcs backend to piplint, It doesn't finds it, then it marks the package as not editable.

See:

[https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/**init**.py#L135](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/__init__.py#L135)

[https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/vcs/**init**.py#L60](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/vcs/__init__.py#L60)

Maybe it's a bug in pip or in piplint  setup.py.

Comment: When you link to source always link to specific version as `develop` is a moving target.

Comment: You should edit your answer adding link to pip issue instead of adding a comment.

Comment: @fabiocerqueira I'm not sure that svn bug is exactly the same (although the symptom is the same, can't find the vcs backend). I posted a separate bug here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/713